# rebuild a jenkins job without changes show failure status

Tags: jenkins

i am using jenkins-cloudformation-plugin to run a cloudformation script.my issue is that if i rebuild a job without any changes in the script jenkins show failure status while it it shouldn’t fail until it’s a failure.here is the error

```
Updating Cloud Formation stack: cfn-jenkins-demo
Failed to create stack: cfn-jenkins-demo. Reason: Detailed Message: No updates are to be performed. (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: d180d7f6-e2ad-4090-bfbb-5625f5194cd4)
Status Code: 400
Error Code: ValidationError
[Slack Notifications] found #13 as previous completed, non-aborted build
[Slack Notifications] will send OnEveryFailureNotification because build matches and user preferences allow it
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You will need to post your Jenkinsfile/Jenkins Job configuration or it is hard to guess what you did wrong. It could be missing quotes like https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9081 or you are trying to update a template without changing the template (see: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/376#issuecomment-344757802)

Comment: i'm trying o update a template without changing it

Comment: Well, that is simply not allowed/possible. You will need to check if your template has changed before you try to update it.
Another option would be to "ignore" the return value of your update step. That way your Jenkins Job/Pipeline will always pass this step. unfortunately you will not get an error if it failed for a "good" reason. So you should prefer the first option. Still: if you could share your Jenkins Job Configuration/pipeline we could give you a better response with better examples on how to solve this.